# Non printable characters during model training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-2

I am training on a timeseries dataset using conv1D but during training I am getting non printable characters along with training status like

> 2044/42401 [>.............................] - ETA: 1:12 - loss: 0.5781 - accuracy: 0.7441

So I loaded the dataset using

```
pandas.read_csv method using encoding='utf_8'
```

The dataset has NaN values that I have removed using dropna and fillna, like below.

```
dataset = dataset.dropna(thresh=4)
x_train = x_train.fillna(0)
```

But the non-printable characters stays. How can I remove them?
I have Keras 2.2.4, tensorflow 2.2.0 and tensorflow is running as the backend.

Comment: one naive solution is to create cleanDataset function where you can check if the data is within the valid ASCII range you define.

Comment: Is encoding='utf_8' not sufficient for that?